# Early stopping in Caffe

Tags: caffe

Seems [this related PR](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/76) is dead now, is there any workaround to use [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping) in Caffe? maybe using python on top of Caffe?

Comment: you can always <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> to stop caffe and make it dump the current `solverstate`.

Comment: @Shai I don't need start\stop functionality, but I need stop by criterion.

Comment: What kind of early stopping criterion do you want? Just as the PR's? If it is, you can simply add a counter and a threshold in the solver to check whether the training should be stopped.

Comment: @Dale do you mean I need to add new solver type in C++ and recompile Caffe?

Comment: Yes. I think you need to, because I think `pycaffe` doesn't have an suitable interface to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

A first part is easy to do manually: let monitor your validation error then stop when this one do not change a lot (below a threshold). Then let consider the state with the lowest validation error as the "optimal" network.

The real problem is then to benefit from the full train+val dataset from there. There are two basic strategies:

1. Retrain your network with train+val for the same number of epoch OR for the same number of data (i.e let compute the number of minibatches that were used to reach the "optimal" state and set the number of passes such that the same number of minibatches (with same size...) go through the network
2. Let keep the "optimal" network then add the validation data and continue the training. If you reach the same error rate as before, let stop. Else, let just fix an a priori number of epochs.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply [this patch for early stopping](http://ai.terrawx.com/early-stop.html) to standard Caffe RC 1.0.0. It adds an optional `early_stop_param` into the solver. You can specify the test network ID, the length of tries to check for improvement in the test loss and a "skip" so that not every iteration is tried. Disclosure: I am one of the developers.